# jsoup login and parse html

Tags: java, web-scraping, web-crawler, jsoup

the problem is: when I login to the website it directs to a home page every time. but I want to connect with different page to parse its html and download from it, so the document in the last connect directs to login again

```
try {
            
            Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect("https://10.232.1.220/123Mobile/Portal/")
                    .userAgent(USER_AGENT)
                    .sslSocketFactory(utilService.socketFactory())
                    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                    .execute();

            //Login 
            
            FormElement loginForm = (FormElement)response.parse().select("form[class=login-form]").first();
            checkElement("Login Form", loginForm);
            Element loginField = loginForm.select("input[name=UserName]").first();
            checkElement("Login Field", loginField);
            loginField.val(internalConstant.getEbcUsename());
            Element passwordField = loginForm.select("input[name=Password]").first();
            checkElement("Password Field", passwordField);
            passwordField.val(internalConstant.getEbcPassword());
            response = loginForm.submit()
                     .cookies(response.cookies())
                     .userAgent(USER_AGENT)  
                     .method(Method.POST)
                     .sslSocketFactory(utilService.socketFactory())
                     .followRedirects(false)
                     .execute();
            
            logger.info("home html: " + response.parse());
            //target document
            
            Document targetPage = Jsoup.connect("https://10.232.1.220/123Mobile/Portal/Reports/TransactionReport")
                    .userAgent(USER_AGENT)
                    .sslSocketFactory(utilService.socketFactory())
                    .cookies(response.cookies())
                    .get();
            
            logger.info("target document html: " + targetPage.html());

            if (ebcFile.isEmpty()) {
                logger.error("file not found");

                throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Ebc File not found in website");
            }

            // this.FileDownloaderService.downloadExcelFile(ebcFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.error("download error " + e.getMessage());
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Failed to download file");
        }
```

Comment: **URL:** `https://10.232.1.220/123Mobile/Portal/` results in the following **HTTP Response:** `This site can’t be reached 10.232.1.220 took too long to respond.`

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using `.followRedirects(false)`? Sometimes user is redirected after login and you may be skipping something. Did you try displaying cookies from the response and comparing them with cookies you get in the web browser?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the response of submit cookie doesn't has the sessionid and the request token cookies, so I added them from the login response.

```
Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(internalConstant.getLoginURL())
                    .userAgent(USER_AGENT)
                    .sslSocketFactory(utilService.socketFactory())
                    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                    .execute();
            
            logger.info("response cookies after parse login page: " + response.cookies());
            String sesionID = response.cookie(your cookie);
            String requestCookie = response.cookie(your cookie);

            //Login 
            
            FormElement loginForm = (FormElement)response.parse().select("form[class=login-form]").first();
            checkElement("Login Form", loginForm);
            Element loginField = loginForm.select("input[name=UserName]").first();
            checkElement("Login Field", loginField);
            loginField.val(internalConstant.getEbcUsename());
            
            Element passwordField = loginForm.select("input[name=Password]").first();
            checkElement("Password Field", passwordField);
            passwordField.val(internalConstant.getEbcPassword());
            response = loginForm.submit()
                     .cookies(response.cookies())
                     .userAgent(USER_AGENT)  
                     .method(Method.POST)
                     .sslSocketFactory(utilService.socketFactory())
                     .execute();
            Map<String , String> coky = response.cookies();
            coky.put("your cookie", requestCookie);
            coky.put("your cookie", sesionID);
            
            logger.info("response cookies after submit: " + coky);
            
            
            //target document
            
             response = Jsoup.connect(internalConstant.getURL())
                    .userAgent(USER_AGENT)
                    .sslSocketFactory(utilService.socketFactory())
                    .cookies(coky)
                    .method(Method.GET)
                    .execute();
```